# How to fetch meta_value and meta_key in matrix after ajax request by post_id

Tags: ajax, query, meta-value

Well, I have 2 custom post types:

A = Properties
B = Property Owners

Inside CPT Properties, I was created a Meta Box to:

1. Search a registred Owner (CPT) by VAT number (CPF in Brazil)
2. Relate Owner with de Property

I have the CPTs and Meta Boxes. The Meta Boxe "Search Onwer" it is making the ajax request to the server, using this query

```
function getOwner($post){

    global $wpdb;
    $cpfcode = $wpdb->escape($post['cpfCode']);

    $query =    'SELECT 
                    post_id,
                    meta_key, 
                    meta_value
                FROM
                    wp_postmeta
                WHERE 
                    post_id = (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = "'.$cpfcode.'");';


    $keys = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

    if ($keys) { return $keys; } else { echo "error"; };
    exit();
}
```

and returning an json object with the meta_values and meta_keys like this:

```
[
    {
        "post_id"   :"112",
        "meta_key"  :"owner_vat",
        "meta_value":"123.456.789-10"
    },

    {
        "post_id"   :"112",
        "meta_key"  :"owner_name",
        "meta_value":"Jonh Doe"
    },

    {   
        "post_id"   :"112",
        "meta_key"  :"owner_city",
        "meta_value":"Rio de Janeiro"
    },
]
```

Now, I need, using jQuery, insert this values in some fields. The problem is do the each or the for, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
function loadOwner_sel(dta,selval) {
   var
        array = JSON.parse(dta),
        obj = {};

        jQuery.each(array, function(index, item) {
            obj[item.meta_key] = item.meta_value;
        });
        document.getElementById('owner_name').value = obj.owner_name;
}
```